# Difference in the number of purchase events and revenue on GA4 dashboard and Website dashboard

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've implemented purchase events on a site using tagmanager. Now, I'm facing an issue with the total event count and revenue. When I compare the number of purchase events and revenue on the GA4 dashboard with the count and amount displayed on the backend of the website, the GA4 dashboard shows less count.

When a user makes a purchase, they will be redirected to a thank you page (there are a total of 5 thank you pages depending on the type of purchase) and from these thank you pages, we push the data to the data layer. The tagmanager tracking code is added in the head and body of the thank you pages, only on the thank you pages.

Below is the script we use to push data to the data layer.

```
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    window.dataLayer.push({ ecommerce:null })
    window.dataLayer.push({
        event: 'purchase',
        ecommerce: {
            currency: 'EUR',
            value: #Price#,
            transaction_id: '##TransactionID##',
            items: [{
                item_name: '#Item Name#',
                item_id: '#Item Name#',
                price: #Price#,
                quantity: 1
            }]
        }
    });
</script>
```

Below is the difference in the count of events.

27-09-2022 - Backend - 1199, GA Dashboard - 1136

26-09-2022 -Backend - 1925, GA Dashboard - 1306

25-09-2022 - Backend - 866, GA Dashboard - 818

24-09-2022 - Backend - 929, GA Dashboard - 893

23-09-2022 - Backend - 1375, GA Dashboard - 1292.

When I used the Chat option in GA4, they suggested that it is an issue with the Tag Manager.
But I couldn't figure out it.

Could someone please enlighten me as to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A discrepancy between 5 and 10% between the database and Analytics data is physiological. There are several reasons why this can happen: JavaScript error, Ad-blocker, type of browser used by the user, slow loading of the page, user not returning to the website from the payment system, consent mode, etc...

In your case, apart from one case, the others are all around 5 or 6%. I would say that everything is normal.

To have 100% of the transactions you should adopt a server-to-server conversion tracking system.